# nextcord.ext.commands.errors.ChannelNotFound: Channel "None" not found. (nextcord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I am making a ticket system with nextcord.py, a discord.py maintained fork. My setup command requires you specify a category ID in which new ticket channels will be created. Here is the command:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def setup(self, client, context, message : nextcord.Message=None, category : nextcord.CategoryChannel=None):
        if message is None or category is None:
            await context.channel.send("Ticket system configuration failure.")
            return

        client.ticket_configs[context.guild.id] = [message.id, message.channel.id, category.id]        

        async with aiofiles.open("ticket_configs.txt", mode="r") as file:
            data = await file.readlines()

        async with aiofiles.open("ticket_configs.txt", mode="w") as file:
            await file.write(f"{context.guild.id} {message.id} {message.channel.id} {category.id}\n")

            for line in data:
                if int(line.split(" ")[0]) != context.guild.id:
                    await file.write(line)
                    
        await message.add_reaction(u"\U0001F3AB")
        await context.channel.send("Ticket system successfully configured!")
```

When I run this command in Discord, it raises this error in the terminal:

```
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.ChannelNotFound: Channel "None" not found.
```

This error is also raised when I remove `=None` from the `category : nextcord.CategoryChannel`.

All help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

##### Ok, here's a few potential problems:

- Dumb question, but if you're using `nextcord.Client`, you cannot use `nextcord.ext.commands`, so use `nextcord.ext.commands.Bot` instead
- You're doing `async def setup(self, client, context, ...` but if you're using a cog, you access `client` with `self.client` (if you defined it in `__init__`), and in the actual command function you just do `async def example(self, context)`
- 99% sure you can't call your function `setup` just because Nextcord runs `setup` when the cog is loaded so do something like this:

```py
@commands.command(name='setup')
async def setupCommand(...):
```